# How to build a simple search engine using Solr / Lucene?

Tags: search, web, solr, lucene

I'm totally new to Solr. My professor ask me to build a search engine that can search some causations and conditional texts with Solr. 
Now I have already build a core and import some text data into Solr server and can query them on the Solr Admin. But I don't know how to build a search engine that have a web interface like google or other search engine and integrate it with Solr. Please tell me how to do it by step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick some programming language and use one of the libraries available for that language to communicate with Solr. In the end, you could write your own library firing HTTP requests again the Solr server, but usually, a library abstracting you of this is already available.

For example, if you want to use PHP, you could use the [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) library, so could write your web interface using the usual technologies (HTML, CSS, JS) and the backend of your application will be written in PHP (which will communicate with Solr and execute the queries that you specify).

If you want a more direct approach (skip PHP, for example) and you have no problem exposing the Solr server to the public (a really really bad idea, unless you put some sort of proxy between Solr and the user) you could use something like [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) this will allow you to fire Solr queries directly from the browser (similar to how the Solr Admin UI works).

Comment: thx! I think Ajax-solr is what I want. Thanks for helping me!